# ggplot two gradient fills on one plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've been producing animated maps showing the progression of COVID case data.  In the interest of producing a minimal example I have skinnied the code down to the below, which only produces one frame.  In practice I also read a number of csv files.  I've tried to eliminate that in this example, but there is still one with county population data.  I have posted it at https://pastebin.com/jCD9tP0X

```
library(urbnmapr) # For map
library(ggplot2)  # For map
library(dplyr)    # For summarizing
library(tidyr)    # For reshaping
library(stringr)  # For padding leading zeros
library(ggrepel)
library(ggmap)
library(usmap)
library(gganimate)
library(magrittr)
library(gifski)
library(scales)


#first run setup tasks
#these can be commented out once the data frames are in place

###################begin first run only################################

#define census regions
NE_region <- c("ME","NH","VT","MA", "CT", "RI", "NY", "PA", "NJ")

ne_region_bases <-c("Hanscom AFB", "Rome, NY")

# Get COVID cases, available from:
url <- "https://static.usafacts.org/public/data/covid-19/covid_confirmed_usafacts.csv"
COV <- read.csv(url, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#sometimes there are encoding issues with the first column name
names(COV)[1] <- "countyFIPS"

Covid <- pivot_longer(COV, cols=starts_with("X"),
                      values_to="cases",
                      names_to=c("X","date_infected"),
                      names_sep="X") %>%
  mutate(infected = as.Date(date_infected, format="%m.%d.%Y"),
         countyFIPS = str_pad(as.character(countyFIPS), 5, pad="0"))

# Obtain map data for counties (to link with covid data) and states (for showing borders)
states_sf <- get_urbn_map(map = "states", sf = TRUE)
counties_sf <- get_urbn_map(map = "counties", sf = TRUE)

# Merge county map with total cases of cov
#use this line to produce animated maps
#pop_counties_cov <- inner_join(counties_sf, Covid, by=c("county_fips"="countyFIPS"))

#use this one for a single map of the latest data
pop_counties_cov <- inner_join(counties_sf, group_by(Covid, countyFIPS) %>%
                             summarise(cases=sum(cases)), by=c("county_fips"="countyFIPS"))

#read the county population data
#csv at https://pastebin.com/jCD9tP0X
counties_pop <- read.csv("countyPopulations.csv", header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

#pad the single digit state FIPS states
counties_pop <- counties_pop %>% mutate(CountyFIPS=str_pad(as.character(CountyFIPS),5,pad="0"))

#merge the population and covid data by FIPS
pop_counties_cov$population <- counties_pop$Population[match(pop_counties_cov$county_fips,counties_pop$CountyFIPS)]

#calculate the infection rate
pop_counties_cov <- pop_counties_cov %>% mutate(infRate = (cases/population)*100)

#counties with 0 infections don't appear in the usafacts data, so didn't get a population
#set them to 0
pop_counties_cov$population[is.na(pop_counties_cov$population)] <- 0
pop_counties_cov$infRate[is.na(pop_counties_cov$infRate)] <- 0

plotDate="April14"
basepath = "your/output file/path/here/"
naColor = "white"
lowColor = "green"
midColor = "maroon"
highColor = "red"
baseFill = "dodgerblue4"
baseColor = "firebrick"
baseShape = 23
###################end first run only################################


###################Northeast Map################################
#filter out states
ne_pop_counties_cov <- pop_counties_cov %>% filter(state_abbv %in% NE_region)
ne_states_sf <- states_sf %>% filter(state_abbv %in% NE_region)
ne_counties_sf <- counties_sf %>% filter(state_abbv %in% NE_region)

#filter out bases
neBases <- structure(list(Base = c("Hanscom AFB", "Rome, NY"), longitude = c(-71.2743123, 
                                                                             -75.4557303), 
                          latitude = c(42.4579955, 43.2128473), 
                          personnel = c(2906L,822L), 
                          longitude.1 = c(2296805.44531269, 1951897.82199569), 
                          latitude.1 = c(128586.352781279, 99159.9145180969)), 
                          row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = "data.frame")

p <- ne_pop_counties_cov %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = infRate, geometry=geometry), color = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = ne_states_sf, fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.25) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA) +   
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "% Pop \nInfected", trans = "log",low=lowColor, high=highColor,
                      breaks=c(0, max(ne_pop_counties_cov$infRate)),
                      na.value = naColor) +
  geom_point(data=neBases, 
             aes(x=longitude.1, y=latitude.1,size=personnel), 
             shape = baseShape,
             color = baseColor,
             fill = baseFill) +
  theme_bw() + 
  labs(size='AFMC \nMil + Civ') +
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank())

print(p)

###################End Northeast Map################################
```

If you run this you should get a single frame...when I do the whole animation, here is the final frame

[image]

The diamonds represent the locations of air force bases we're interested in within the region, and they are sized by how many personnel are there.

What I have been asked to do is to make the diamonds the same size, but "color code" the fill based on the number of personnel.  I don't think this is a good idea, but I'm not the boss.

I'm not sure how to have two gradient fills on a single plot?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to place a second filling gradient, you can have the use of `new_scale_fill` function from `ggnewscale` package:

```r
library(ggnewscale)

p <- ne_pop_counties_cov %>%
  ggplot() +
  geom_sf(mapping = aes(fill = infRate, geometry=geometry), color = NA) +
  geom_sf(data = ne_states_sf, fill = NA, color = "black", size = 0.25) +
  coord_sf(datum = NA) +   
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "% Pop \nInfected", trans = "log",low=lowColor, high=highColor,
                      breaks=c(0, max(ne_pop_counties_cov$infRate)),
                      na.value = naColor) +
  new_scale_fill()+
  geom_point(data=neBases, 
             aes(x=longitude.1, y=latitude.1,fill=personnel), 
             shape = baseShape,
             color = "black",
             #fill = baseFill,
             size = 5) +
  scale_fill_gradient(name = "AFMC \nMil + Civ",
                      low = "blue", high = "magenta",
                      breaks = c(1,max(neBases$personnel)))+
  theme_bw() + 
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        panel.border = element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(), 
        axis.title.y=element_blank())

print(p)
```

[image]

Does it answer your question ?